# How to make multiple Delphi projects auto compile?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I have 127 Delphi XE4 Applications and I would like to make a system such a way that all these Delphi applications get compiled one by one automatically.

If Anyone have any good idea how to do that with Delphi IDE then that would be highly appreciated.

P.S. If there's no simple way and I need to write a separate utility in Delphi that is also fine.

Comment: Add them into a project group and select Compile All?

Comment: Let me check. Thank You.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of projects. Do they all have different code?

Comment: Yes, They all have different code, but some of them are related to each other i.e. functions calling done with each other. Any suggetions on this ?

Comment: Seems odd that you really have that many different programs. Was wondering if you really need config files, or conditionals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways would be to create a Delphi project group:

1. Open any project in Delphi.
2. Open Project Manager tab (usually it's on the right)
3. Right-click `ProjectGroup1` line and select `Add Existing project ...`, add DPR projects you need
4. Repeat step 3 for all projects you want to be included into a batch
5. Save newly assembled Project Group, it will have `.groupproj` extension
6. Now you can choose `Projects > Compile All Projects` to batch-compile everything

Another way is to use command-line compiling, e.g. with a batch file like

```
call  "<ProgramFiles>\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
MSBuild YourProject.dproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release
```

You can add something like this as an entry to the Windows Explorer context menu for `.dproj`.

If you want to compile with special options you can define a configuration (similar to Debug/Release) and pass that to MSBuild. Maybe you can use option sets - never tried that since I'm still on D2007.

Comment: It's worth to mention that you can build project groups from command line (by MSBuild) to move the build *automation* outside the Delphi IDE.

Comment: Hi TLama, could you please let me know, how it could be done ? Thank You.

Comment: Is there any way that programatically we could invoke any menu and sub-menu option in Delphi XE ?

For Example, is it possible through Delphi program to invoke any Delphi project file and the invoke Tools menu, then get invoked 'Options...' sub-menu automatically and get selected any options as per requirement.

Comment: First `call` `rsvars.bat` from the `bin` directory in your Delphi installation. Afterwards call something like `MSBuild <ProjectName.dproj> /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release`.

Comment: Re your options comment: Define a configuration (similar to Debug/Release) and pass that to MSBuild. Maybe you can use option sets - never tried that since I'm still on D2007.

Comment: How about invoking Menu, Sub-Menu and Selecting or Deselecting the options via programming ?

Comment: @Krom Stern: Fine, I would do that right away. Thank You.